# How to use the .so file in my project？

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the "beginner tutorial" to study the ROS, now I want to build a new project which communicates with the robot by using the Serial Port. I searched the packages and found the "cereal_port", I downloaded the source , compiled and got the "libcereal_port.so" file. I used the Eclipse to develop the code and tried to find how to use the .so file in Eclipse, however, I added the .so in the /lib and modified the project configuration which added the file as a library, it can't be found, the "#include <cereal_port/CerealPort.h>" gave an error.

Could anyone please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60441/how-to-use-the-.so-file-in-my-project%EF%BC%9F/) by [Chris_Tian](https://answers.ros.org/users/4659/chris_tian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the 'cereal port' download and install (with rosmake) this package == > http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/serial_communication/. I have used this to work with my Roomba 560 robot (https://github.com/Arkapravo/roomba_500_ROS_drivers).Hope that solves your problem. Just a tip, please mention the version of ROS (and other softwares, Eclipse in your case) in your future postings here.

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1